# Laravel limiting scope of models automatically based on API user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model

I have an API that uses bearer tokens for authentication. Bearer tokens are stored against users. There is some middleware that checks if there is a valid bearer token in the request, and 401's if not.

Given I can infer the user from the token, I'm wanting to limit the scope of all model lookups in this API controller to only show results from the users company id.

**Does Laravel have some neat magic way of doing this?** Or am I going to be looking up the user again in the controller constructor and adding where clauses into every single action?

---

**Basically I'm wanting to avoid having to do this:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    # 401 if there isn't a valid bearer token in the request
    $this->middleware('apitokencheck');

    # Boo to this
    $user = UsersModel::where("api_token", $request->api_token)->first();
    $this->companyContext = CompaniesModel::find($user->company_id);
}

...

public function get(Request $request)
{
    # Boo to this also
    $where = [ 
        "company_id" => $this->companyContext->id
    ];

    # Filters
    return InspectionsModel::where($where)->get();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered global scopes? They seem to be on purpose: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: @dparoli if you put that as an answer I'll mark that as correct thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea, you could make a middleware to associate company context with the incoming request. Let's call it "AddCompanyContextMiddleware" which will look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AddCompanyContextMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = UsersModel::where("api_token", $request->api_token)->first();
        $request['companyContext'] = CompaniesModel::find($user->company_id);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now you can register the middleware through Kernel and associate it with as many routes as you like, so that when the control gets to COntroller, your `$request` variable will already have `companyContext` in it and then in controller you can use the info however you like:

```
public function get(Request $request)
{
    $companyContext = $request->input('companyContext');
    # Boo to this also
    $where = [ 
        "company_id" => $companyContext->id
    ];

    # Filters
    return InspectionsModel::where($where)->get();
}
```

Makes sense?